# TableDependency.SqlClient.Exceptions.UserWithNoPermissionException: 'User without permissions.' In using SqlTableDependency

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I have this to listen to changes in the table in SQL Server

```
DataBaseWatcher.Customers =
                        new TableDependency.SqlClient.SqlTableDependency<CustomersAndVendors>(Properties.Settings.Default.SalesDBConnectionString,
                        filter: new DataBaseWatcher.CustomersOnly());
                    DataBaseWatcher.Customers.OnChanged += DataBaseWatcher.Customers_Changed;
                    DataBaseWatcher.Customers.Start();
```

But I get the following error

TableDependency.SqlClient.Exceptions.UserWithNoPermissionException: 'User without permissions.'

I think there are missing user permissions, but I don't know how to give them

Comment: Have you read how to setup the table dependency? For example here: https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency

Comment: Yes, I followed all the steps, but I still get the same error: User without permissions.